# Find documents by an array of objects

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to create a query in MongoDB to to find documents by and array of objects which exactly math document property.

I have documents:

```
{meta: {prop1: "hi1", prop2: "ho1"}},
{meta: {prop1: "hi2", prop2: "ho2"}},
{meta: {prop1: "hi3", prop2: "ho3"}},
{meta: {prop1: "hi1", prop2: "ho2"}}
```

I want to find documents whose `meta` property is one of exact objects in this array:

```
[
  {prop1: "hi1", prop2: "ho1"}, {prop1: "hi2", prop2: "ho2"}
]
```

Desired result would be documents:

```
{meta: {prop1: "hi1", prop2: "ho1"}},
{meta: {prop1: "hi2", prop2: "ho2"}}
```

but not:

```
{meta: {prop1: "hi1", prop2: "ho1"}},
{meta: {prop1: "hi2", prop2: "ho2"}},
{meta: {prop1: "hi1", prop2: "ho2"}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [$in](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) operator.

```
Collection.find({
    meta:  { 
        $in: [
            { prop1: 'hi1', prop2: 'ho1'}, 
            { prop1: 'hi2', prop2: 'ho2'}
        ]
    } 
})
```

Answer (score 0):

We can Use `$or` for this -

```
Collection.find({
        $or: [
            {'meta.prop1': 'hi1', 'meta.prop2': 'ho1'},
            { 'meta.prop1': 'hi2', 'meta.prop2': 'ho2'}
        ]
})
```

**Note**: inside object of $or, $and condition is build.

We can use `$in` also because **$in is inbuilt using $or**.